# Entity framework - own type filed

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I'm all new to EF and I'm looking for using my own type.
Can I use this type to map it to field at database.
Normally I should map:

DateTime to Date (Oracle)

I need to map:

MyDateType to Date (Oracle)

Can anybody help me to make it?
Is it possible? Maybe other ORM can make it?

Answer (score 0):

U can use another not mapped property of your own type:

```
 public DateTime Date{ get; set; }//this is mapped to db

 [NotMapped]
 public MyDateType MyDateTimeProperty
 {
    get { return /*conversion from DateTime to MyDateType */; }
    set { Date= /*conversion from MyDateType to DateTime*/; }
 }
```